# What is the best/easiest way to use scripts to analyze network traffic?

Tags: networking, security, scripting, analysis

I'm looking to analyze packets via scripts. I'd like to use something high level. I'm in a mac/linux environment. I'm currently looking at different python+libpcap libraries. Perhaps lua+wireshark too. Maybe tcpdump+bash (but not sure that has a lot of info i can use). I also heard good things about scapy. Not sure.

I'm wondering if you have any recommendations? There's quite a few of them out there. What have you found that works best? I'd definitely want something scriptable not something that I need to compile (like c/c++, etc)

Answer (score 1):

shameless plug: my [Lua libpcap binding](http://github.com/javierguerragiraldez/pcaplua)

Comment: no shame there, good job!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it goes deep enough for your needs, but grabbing the stdout of wiresharks little bro TSHARK has worked for me in the past. It's got some very powerful statistical options:

http://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/tshark.html